# AWS-PHP-SDK / SNS direct addressing returns error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

Hi I am using Laravel 4 setup to make use of AWS SNS to send a push message to my iOS device, the publish command to my device works well from AWS console.

I then tried from PHP:

```
    $sns = AWS::get('sns');

    $sns->publish(array(
        'Message' => 'Hello from PHP',
        'TargetArn' => "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:360542326270:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/Testtest/20a75cd1-da25-3331-8126-4db497cbdd5e"
    ));
```

I am getting

```
Guzzle \ Service \ Exception \ ValidationException Validation errors: [TopicArn] is a required string: The topic you want to publish to.
```

but the docs specifically say I can use publish to either send to a topic ARN or use direct addressing to send to a single device directly.

it seems the AWS PHP SDK forces me to use TopicArn anyway.

[http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+(Amazon+Web+Services+Blog)](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+%28Amazon+Web+Services+Blog%29)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the SDK and Guzzle do you have installed?

Comment: I ask because I cannot reproduce the error. I copied your code and ran  it, but the Guzzle validation succeeds just fine as it should.

Comment: I have composer doing that for me, I had "guzzle/guzzle": "3.6.*" and now I added "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "1.*". so I got Guzzle 3.6.0 and AWS-PHP-SDK 2.3.4

Comment: worked.. see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed the explicit guzzle line from composer. then ran update, it removed guzzle 3.6 and installed 3.9. it then removed AWS-PHP-SDK 2.3.4 and installed dev-master

I then tried it and it worked.

not sure what was the problem, but different packages versions did not work together...

Comment: The problem is that version 2.3.4 of the SDK did not yet support mobile push notifications, so the TopicArn *was* required at that time.

Comment: It's good to explicitly declare your dependencies in your project's composer.json, for example: `{"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~1.1", "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.6", "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.9.0"}`, and stay up-to-date, especially with the SDK.